# Get an array of select options as a string in ionic2 angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to get the values from `select` multiple of ionic2.

My html is

```
<ion-select name="days" [(ngModel)]="appointment.days" multiple="true">
    <ion-option value="mon" selected="true">Monday</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="tue">Tuedsay</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="wed">Wednesday</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="thu">Thursday</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="fri">Friday</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

`recurrence_days: this.appointment.days,`

however above code output the value in the form of array. But I want log that value as text. Any idea ?

Array after executing my code.

[image]

Comment: Don't post text as pictures, copy-paste it instead.

Comment: What output are you expecting? Some textual representation of an array?

Comment: Yes I wanted to display textual representation of an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join method,

```
let result = recurrence_days.join("\n")
```